# when working with missing data, what percentage of data is considered too much missing before implementing something like imputation?

Tags: missing-data, data-imputation, multiple-imputation

I am looking for advice (do not have a specific example regarding data) but am wondering, when working with any dataset that is missing, at what point/percentage would you consider using something like multiple imputation to account for missing data?

I am aware that there are assumptions that need to be held before proceeding with multiple imputation but in general what percentage of missing data would yo consider to be too much missing data?

What other tools/procedures would you recomend apart from multiple imputation?

Answer (score 2):

> at what point/percentage would you consider using something like multiple imputation to account for missing data?

Stef van Buuren discusses this in Section 1.3.1 of [Flexible Imputation of Missing Data](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-simplesolutions.html) (FIMD), "Listwise Deletion:"

> The leading authors in the field are, however, wary of providing advice about the percentage of missing cases below which it is still acceptable to do listwise deletion.

I'm not a leading author in the field, so I'll follow that advice for addressing your question. Also:

> The implications of the missing data are different depending on where they occur (outcomes or predictors), and the parameter and model form of the complete-data model.

For example, as van Buuren says in [Section 2.7](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-when.html):

> If the missing data occur in [outcome] $Y$ only, complete-case analysis and multiple imputation are equivalent, so then complete-case analysis is preferred since it is easier, more efficient and more robust.

In that situation, no percentage of missing data would require multiple imputation, at least in terms of estimating regression coefficients.

Frank Harrell devotes Chapter 3 of [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/missing.html) to ways to handle missing data. He summarizes practical suggestions in [Section 3.10](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/missing.html#summary-and-rough-guidelines), but warns that "Simulation studies are needed to refine the recommendations." The general idea is that increasing fractions of cases with missing data require more imputed data sets for reliable results.

Thus with very small fractions of missing-data cases (subject to the above warning, he suggests <3% of cases), single imputation or listwise deletion can work well enough. Even then, he says "Multiple imputation may be needed to check that the simple approach 'worked.'"

What's important, whatever decision you make, is to state how you handled the missing data in reports, so that others can try to reproduce or improve upon your analysis.